# Compression algorithm for integers (for 12, 13, .... bits integers)

Tags: python, integer, compression, archive

I’m working on a project that deals with compressing binary. All compression software I have tried (including Zip and RAR) read 8-bit blocks of data and their compression algorithms are based on 8-bit readings of data (or a multiplier of 8).

I wonder if I can find a compression algorithm that can compress data based on n-bit data blocks? By “n”, I mean for example 12 bits, 13 bits, or even 22 bits.

Comment: When working with bits you usually work with nibbles or bytes (i.e. 4, or 8 bit increments) because that is how the computer or embedded board works with the data. Why do you want to work with a random number of bits? (Ex 13)

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Thank you. As I wrote above in my project I work with integers, for example in a file I have 200K integers that represents 4000 or 5000 numbers (each integer comes around 500/400 times)  . After writing these integers on a file (12/13 bits), I would like to compress it with good ratio. Unfortunately I can’t define 12 or 13 bits to the compression software. Because of that I don’t have compression!

Comment: Write it to a file as 16 bits (i.e. buffer it to 16 bits), then let the compression tools do there job.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Thanks for your hint. I did it but it doesn’t work. I add around 1 MB to the file (12+4=16 bits) then compress it only 1 MB.